# Iterate an array using its length inside a nested ngFor loop - Angular 9

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

Im iterating an array of objects and inside of each of this objects there is another array of objects with values such as "name" and "id". This array of objects (called noticias) have a variable length.

I need to display this values, I've only been able to access and display them by hardcoding the "X" shown below.

```
<div *ngFor="let c of DATA; let i = index;">
  {{i}}{{c.name}}   

  <div *ngFor="let novedad of DATA; let i2 = index; ">
    <div *ngIf="i2 === i">
     {{novedad.noticias[0][X].name | json}}    --> HERE      
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The DATA array comes from a service that uses a series of http calls to form such array.

Is there a way of iterating  `{{novedad.noticias[0][LOOP THROUGH LENGTH OF EACH OBJECT].name | json}}` ?

I hope my question is understandable. Thanks in advance!

JSON object:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Encantamientos",
    "forumid": 6,
    "courseid": 6,
    "type": "news",
    "noticias": [
      "Este curso no tiene novedades"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Historia de la magia",
    "forumid": 5,
    "courseid": 5,
    "type": "news",
    "noticias": [
      [
        {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "aviso 1",
          "groupid": -1,
          "timemodified": 1585598111,
          "usermodified": 3,
          "timestart": 0,
          "timeend": 0,
          "discussion": 9,
          "parent": 0,
          "userid": 3,
          "created": 1585598111,
          "modified": 1585598111,
          "mailed": 0,
          "subject": "aviso 1",
          "message": "<p>aviso1<br /></p>",
          "messageformat": 1,
          "messagetrust": 0,
          "attachment": false,
          "totalscore": 0,
          "mailnow": 0,
          "userfullname": "ignacio ",
          "usermodifiedfullname": "ignacio ",
          "userpictureurl": "link",
          "usermodifiedpictureurl": "link",
          "numreplies": 0,
          "numunread": 0,
          "pinned": false,
          "locked": false,
          "starred": false,
          "canreply": true,
          "canlock": true,
          "canfavourite": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Difusión ",
    "forumid": 1,
    "courseid": 2,
    "type": "news",
    "noticias": [
      [
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "tema difusin 3",
          "groupid": -1,
          "timemodified": 1585595618,
          "usermodified": 3,
          "timestart": 0,
          "timeend": 0,
          "discussion": 8,
          "parent": 0,
          "userid": 3,
          "created": 1585595618,
          "modified": 1585595618,
          "mailed": 0,
          "subject": "tema difusin 3",
          "message": "<p>cuerpo tema difusion 3.<br /></p>",
          "messageformat": 1,
          "messagetrust": 0,
          "attachment": false,
          "totalscore": 0,
          "mailnow": 0,
          "userfullname": "ignacio ",
          "usermodifiedfullname": "ignacio ",
          "userpictureurl": "link",
          "usermodifiedpictureurl": "link",
          "numreplies": 0,
          "numunread": 0,
          "pinned": false,
          "locked": false,
          "starred": false,
          "canreply": true,
          "canlock": true,
          "canfavourite": true
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "2",
          "groupid": -1,
          "timemodified": 1585221896,
          "usermodified": 3,
          "timestart": 0,
          "timeend": 0,
          "discussion": 2,
          "parent": 0,
          "userid": 3,
          "created": 1585221896,
          "modified": 1585221896,
          "mailed": 0,
          "subject": "2",
          "message": "<p>aviso 2<br /></p>",
          "messageformat": 1,
          "messagetrust": 0,
          "attachment": false,
          "totalscore": 0,
          "mailnow": 0,
          "userfullname": "ignacio ",
          "usermodifiedfullname": "ignacio ",
          "userpictureurl": "link",
          "usermodifiedpictureurl": "link",
          "numreplies": 0,
          "numunread": 0,
          "pinned": false,
          "locked": false,
          "starred": false,
          "canreply": true,
          "canlock": true,
          "canfavourite": true
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "aviso 1",
          "groupid": -1,
          "timemodified": 1584460837,
          "usermodified": 3,
          "timestart": 0,
          "timeend": 0,
          "discussion": 1,
          "parent": 0,
          "userid": 3,
          "created": 1584460837,
          "modified": 1584460837,
          "mailed": 0,
          "subject": "aviso 1",
          "message": "<p>aviso 1<br /></p>",
          "messageformat": 1,
          "messagetrust": 0,
          "attachment": false,
          "totalscore": 0,
          "mailnow": 0,
          "userfullname": "ignacio ",
          "usermodifiedfullname": "ignacio ",
          "userpictureurl": link",
          "usermodifiedpictureurl": "link",
          "numreplies": 0,
          "numunread": 0,
          "pinned": false,
          "locked": false,
          "starred": false,
          "canreply": true,
          "canlock": true,
          "canfavourite": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Quimica",
    "forumid": 3,
    "courseid": 4,
    "type": "news",
    "noticias": [
      [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "aviso quimica 3",
          "groupid": -1,
          "timemodified": 1585324962,
          "usermodified": 3,
          "timestart": 0,
          "timeend": 0,
          "discussion": 7,
          "parent": 0,
          "userid": 3,
          "created": 1585324962,
          "modified": 1585324962,
          "mailed": 0,
          "subject": "aviso quimica 3",
          "message": "<p>cuerpo aviso quimica 3<br /></p>",
          "messageformat": 1,
          "messagetrust": 0,
          "attachment": false,
          "totalscore": 0,
          "mailnow": 0,
          "userfullname": "ignacio basti",
          "usermodifiedfullname": "ignacio ",
          "userpictureurl": "link",
          "usermodifiedpictureurl": "link",
          "numreplies": 0,
          "numunread": 0,
          "pinned": false,
          "locked": false,
          "starred": false,
          "canreply": true,
          "canlock": true,
          "canfavourite": true
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "quimica aviso 2",
          "groupid": -1,
          "timemodified": 1585241926,
          "usermodified": 3,
          "timestart": 0,
          "timeend": 0,
          "discussion": 5,
          "parent": 0,
          "userid": 3,
          "created": 1585241926,
          "modified": 1585241926,
          "mailed": 0,
          "subject": "quimica aviso 2",
          "message": "<p>quimica aviso 2</p><p><br /></p>",
          "messageformat": 1,
          "messagetrust": 0,
          "attachment": false,
          "totalscore": 0,
          "mailnow": 0,
          "userfullname": "ignacio ",
          "usermodifiedfullname": "ignacio ",
          "userpictureurl": "link",
          "usermodifiedpictureurl": "link",
          "numreplies": 0,
          "numunread": 0,
          "pinned": false,
          "locked": false,
          "starred": false,
          "canreply": true,
          "canlock": true,
          "canfavourite": true
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "aviso quimica 1",
          "groupid": -1,
          "timemodified": 1585232670,
          "usermodified": 3,
          "timestart": 0,
          "timeend": 0,
          "discussion": 3,
          "parent": 0,
          "userid": 3,
          "created": 1585232670,
          "modified": 1585232670,
          "mailed": 0,
          "subject": "aviso quimica 1",
          "message": "<p>contenido del posteo quimica 1<br /></p>",
          "messageformat": 1,
          "messagetrust": 0,
          "attachment": false,
          "totalscore": 0,
          "mailnow": 0,
          "userfullname": "ignacio ",
          "usermodifiedfullname": "ignacio ",
          "userpictureurl": "link",
          "usermodifiedpictureurl": "",
          "numreplies": 0,
          "numunread": 0,
          "pinned": false,
          "locked": false,
          "starred": false,
          "canreply": true,
          "canlock": true,
          "canfavourite": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you share the entire json?

Comment: i've added it in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure I understand you fully but you should just be able to do:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of DATA; let i = index;">
  {{i}}{{c.name}}   

  <ng-container *ngFor="let inner of c.noticias">
    <div *ngFor="let novedad of inner">
      {{novedad.name | json}}      
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

`ngFor` your `DATA` array, then within each of those, `ngFor` over the `noticias` array, and then once again over the inner as it's an array of arrays.

Comment: Hello! Thanks!
I've shared the json object in the question.
I've tried what you said, but i can still only display the first array adding [0] to `{{novedad[0].name | json}} `  otherwise nothing happens, not even an error.
I think there is something wrong with my data structure but i can't figure out what it is.

Comment: ah yea for some reason your subarray is an array of arrays? I modified my answer adding a 3rd `ngFor`

Comment: yes but your `noticias` isn't an array of objects. it's an array of arrays of objects, not sure why as the outter array seems to always only contain one array that contains multiple objects, and seems redundant

Comment: I must be doing something wrong when composing the array in my service. Is there a fix for moving a level up in the array?

Comment: fix whatever you're doing in the service. or nest more `ngFor` as I have in my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, i have also added the service in my question.

Comment: I can't really read through or make heads or tails of all that

Comment: your nested ngfor answer did the trick.
I have to upgrade my skills obviusly. Pretty new here. Thanks a lot. You saved me hours!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211745/discussion-between-ignacio-basti-and-bryan60).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let c of outerArray; let i = index;">
  {{i}}{{c.name}}   

  <div *ngFor="let novedad of c.innerArray; let i2 = index; ">
    <div *ngIf="i2 === i">
     {{novedad.noticias[i2].name | json}}    --> HERE      
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

As per conceptual and fundamental, it should be like this. Otherwise depends on your response data.